# Does this nodeunit test conform to best practices?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, node.js

I have inherited a node-js project, and I am completely new to it. Fortunately, it is already covered by unit tests.

The class under test, `FmsRescuers`, has the responsibility of sending HTTP requests to a remote server.

My first refactoring was to extract the HTTP behavior into the `HttpRequest` class, to allow testing that an operation requests the correct url with the correct data, without actually performing the http request. The `HttpRequest` class did not previously exist.

I am looking for feedback on the unit test from a perspective of best practices. In particular, how do I best avoid the duplication of calling the `checkIn` function through the different tests?

```
require('../server/extensions');
var FmsRescuers = require('../server/fms_rescuers');
var Rescuer = require('./stubs/helper').Rescuer;

var requestedPath;
var requestedStationNumber;
var requestedRescuerNumber;
var httpRequest = {
    post: function(path, requestData, callback) {
              requestedPath = path;
              requestedStationNumber = requestData.stationNumber;
              requestedRescuerNumber = requestData.rescuerNumber;
              callback('', 200);
          }
};
var rescuers = new FmsRescuers(httpRequest);    
var rescuer = new Rescuer(42, 'Name', new Date().addHours(-2).toTimeZonedString(), new Date().addHours(-1).toTimeZonedString());

exports.testCheckIn = {
    setUp: function(callback) {
               requestedPath = undefined;
               requestedStationNumber = undefined;
               requestedRescuerNumber = undefined;
               callback();
           },
    'check in requests correct path' : function(test) {
        rescuers.checkIn(rescuer, 123, 3, function(result, status) {
            test.equal(requestedPath, '/attendance/checkin');
            test.done();
        });
    },

    'check in sends correct station number' : function(test) {
        rescuers.checkIn(rescuer, 123, 3, function(result, status) {
            test.equal(requestedStationNumber, 123);
            test.done();
        });
    },

    'check in sends correct rescuer number' : function(test) {
        rescuers.checkIn(rescuer, 123, 3, function(result, status) {
            test.equal(requestedRescuerNumber, 42);
            test.done();
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use sinon.js to have the power of spies, stubs and mocks. http://sinonjs.org/

That way you could create a stub of `httpRequest`.

Look for `stub.yield([arg1, arg2, ...])`.

**Edit** I added a code example. I did not fully tested the code, but it's how it would look like.

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
require('../server/extensions');
var FmsRescuers = require('../server/fms_rescuers');
var Rescuer = require('./stubs/helper').Rescuer;

var mockedHttpRequest;
var rescuers;
var rescuer;

exports.testCheckIn = {    
    setUp: function(done) {
        var httpRequest { post: function () {} };
        mockedHttpRequest = sinon.mock(httpRequest);            
        rescuers = new FmsRescuers(mockedHttpRequest);   
        rescuer = new Rescuer(42, 'Name', new Date().addHours(-2).toTimeZonedString(), new Date().addHours(-1).toTimeZonedString());

    },

    'check in requests correct path' : function(test) {
        var expectedPath = '/attendance/checkin'
        mockedHttpRequest
                .expects('post')
                .once()
                .withArgs(expectedPath)
                .yields('', 200);

        rescuers.checkIn(rescuer, 123, 3, function(result, status) {
            mockedHttpRequest.verify();
            test.equal(result, '');
            test.equal(status, 200);
            test.done();
        });
    },
};
```

Comment: I added a code sample.